# Which one is faster for binary search?

Tags: search, binary-search-tree

Which one is faster given a large data (e.g length(data) = 1 billion, where data[i] is type string)?

1. Binary search on a balanced binary tree
2. Binary search on a sorted list

Comment: This depends on specific usage. Please give a specific example and tag a db you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If under sorted list one understands an array (O(1) access), then 2 (the array) is just slightly faster, as a balanced binary tree has the same complexity, but is more indirect, space requiring, as calculated indices.

Both need a logarithmic depth, and as the tree is optimally balanced, the depths are the same.

This is not true for normal binary trees, with varying spine lengths (paths to the leafs), and awkward value distribution (in 1-100 having a root 10). It is clear that for a balanced binary tree much work needs to be done = it is expensive. For huge data one might start with that sorted array and construct the tree from that.

A optimally balanced binary tree is hence an unnecessary overhead.